# Supersized - Jquery - preload just one image

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, slideshow, preload

I have question about preloading – is it possible that Supersized fullscreen-jquery-slideshow load fist slide and shows it and after that preload others slides? So that it not preloading all slides at begining but after page is shown with first image.
Thanks for answer.
Miha

Answer (score 2):

You could make Supersized start after you preload the first image using [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Hm.. but how do I preload just one image? Any example with document.redy? Thx

Comment: You can just add an image with display:none (<img src="aaa.jpg" style="display:none;" />), that would take care of preloading... And I'm not sure how you initialize Supersized, but just put the initialization line in the document.ready. Let me know if you need further assistance, ok?